# Android Socket IO in Service, getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, socket.io

I am running [Gottox's](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) `Socket IO client` for Android. I am starting the connection in an `IntentService` and planning on disconnecting the connection in the same service.

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the `socket.disconnect();` line, but can't figure out why. The SocketIO socket is a class level variable and the `Socket IO` connection is already open when I try to disconnect.

So why am I getting a NPE?

```
public class SocketIOService extends IntentService {

public static final String KEY_ACTION = "action";
public static final String ACTION_START = "start";
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "stop";

private Preferences prefs;
private SocketIO socket;

public SocketIOService() {
    super("com.test.test.SocketIOService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_ACTION);

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_START)) {
        Log.v("SOCKET IO SERVICE", "STARTED");
        prefs = new Preferences(this);

        // Socket IO connection
        try {
            socket = new SocketIO("http://test.test.com:8002");
            SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
            socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                    try { Log.v("SOCKET IO SERVER SAID", json.toString(2)); } 
                    catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                    Log.v("SOCKET IO SERVER SAID", data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                    Log.e("SOCKET IO", "ERROR");
                    socketIOException.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnect() {
                    Log.v("SOCKET IO CONNECTION", "TERMINATED");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnect() {
                    Log.v("SOCKET IO CONNECTION", "ESTABLISHED");
                }

                @Override
                public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                    Log.v("SERVER TRIGGERED EVENT", event);
                }
            });

            // This line is cached until the connection is established.
            socket.emit("userid", prefs.getUserId());
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {
        Log.v("SOCKET IO SERVICE", "STOPPED");
        socket.disconnect();
        stopSelf();
    }

}
```

}

**LOGCAT**

```
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[com.test.test.SocketIOService]
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025):    at com.test.test.SocketIOService.onHandleIntent(SocketIOService.java:89)
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 20:04:49.314: E/AndroidRuntime(15025):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Are you sure the first if gets executed? Do you see the log `Log.v("SOCKET IO SERVER SAID", json.toString(2))`. `socket` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IntentService` doesn't work the same way normal services do. Once it reaches the end of onHandleIntent, it stops itself. What's probably happening is the service makes the socket connection, realizes it's finished doing its work, and stops itself. Then when the Intent with the action `ACTION_STOP` is fired, Android creates a new instance of your service and delivers the Intent, but this instance has not instantiated the socket.

A way to confirm this would be to add `android.util.Log.d("SocketIOService", "" + hashCode());` at the start of onHandleIntent, then proceed as usual. Check your logs to see if the hashCodes are the same -- I expect they will be different, indicating they are different instances of the service.

You probably need to use a regular Service instead and manage your own worker thread in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should test for null first as shown in the codes below:

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {
    if (socket != null) {
        socket.disconnect();            
    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

This would prevent any `NullPointerException` error when you try to close the socket.